# What is the most powerful Jets'n'Guns weapon that can be used with rotary cage?

Tags: jets-and-guns

I'm a heavy user of the *Rotary Cage* and like to aim a bit instead of just blasting. The biggest guns such as *Chronitron Rifle*, *Tesla devastator* and the big laser just shoot straight forward.

What is the biggest gun that can also be turned?

Answer (score 1):

Armageddonator is the biggest gun in the Jets n Guns Gold, but it cannot be turned. The Hydra machine gun is the strongest weapon in Jets n Guns Gold that can be turned with Rotary Cage. Its too expensive, but low heating and a super firepower.